# OnStart in serviceAppliction don't work

Tags: c#, windows-services

I building a service that will edit db data form me.I want to run Encrypt for connectionString when service starts/or recive reuqest and i can't catch the OnStart

What i am diing wrong?

My class

```
  public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        protected void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string stop="";
 //can't get here
 //here Encrypt the section.
 // section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectiond");
        }

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            //my functions
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this a windows service?

Comment: yes,this service is gona be on server Pc and gona send data.

Comment: So why the asp.net and wcf tags??

Answer (score 1):

While debugging a service it's very hard to catch the OnStart method. You can't run a service from Visual Studio, and in production, the OnStart method is already called before you can attach your debugger. What you can do is put the following code in the OnStart method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

This will pop up a window where you can select a debugger. If you have Visual Studio solution already open, you can select this and the debugger will be attached to your service.

To "run your service" from Visual Studio, you can put something like this in your Main():

```
static void Main()
    {
        if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            // Startup as service. 
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyServices() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        else
        {
           //Start things locally here, 
           //for example the same things you do in the OnStart() method of your service
        }
    }
```

Now you can simply run the program from Visual Studio, but it will also work as a service when you install it on your production server...